# Jquery Access Prototype Function parameter values

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Jquery Function has been defined as

```
 $.fn.myFunction = function(options){
    // Some code
 }
```

and it's being called in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.myFunction ({
            param1: 'Value1',
            param2: 'Value2',
        }); 
});
```

My Question is... How I can get the value of param1 and param2 without changing the above code as I can't change the above code. I just need to access param1 and param2 values so I can use it further in the script.

Comment: Which code can't you change? The jQuery function or the call?

Comment: I answered an almost identical question a couple of hours ago, but it looks like it was deleted.

Comment: Yes... Both the code, I can't change.

Comment: You need to check the documentation of the plugin to see if it provides a way to get the parameters that were used.

Comment: If there is no way within the plugin to get the parameter values then your only option is to grab the source with ajax and parse it as text for the values.